# Issues Configuring Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am having trouble setting up dropzonejs with my form. I currently have a form with no url attribute (form is submitted and files are handled via my controller's index function). What I want to do is to choose the files on the client side and handled the processing via php (using codeigniter framework). Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? Dropzone is not showing up on my page even after adding the dropzone js/css files.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" class="form dropzone">
    <label>Select Your File(s) : </label><input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"/><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
<script>
    $(function() {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
       Dropzone.options.form1 = {
           paramName: 'filesToUpload',
           uploadMultiple: true
       }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check the docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage), it is quite straightforward.

1. You have no `url` specified.  Dropzone will use the `action` attributed of the Dropzone form, but your form has no `action`.  Nor do your options specify a `url`.
2. You should not include a file input unless you are providing it as a fallback for non-Javascript browsers (and your code is not doing that).  Remove your `#filesToUpload` input.
3. Files are uploaded automatically, so you don't need a submit button, remove it.  If you do want to use a button, you need to disable `autoProcessQueue`, and then manually `processQueue()` when your button is clicked.

I'd suggest starting with a very basic version and get that working before expanding and customising it to suit.  There's [a simple example](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage) shown in the docs:

```
<form action="/file-upload"
  class="dropzone"
  id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

That's it.  No JS required for this.  Add your real upload URL as the `action`, and get that working.  Once you have that done, if it doesn't exactly match what you need, start customising, one thing at a time.  If you're having trouble, look at your browser's devtools, check the Network tab - you will be able to see the requests Dropzone is POSTing, you can examine what is being sent, and the server response.

[Read through the docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage), they really are good and everything you need is there :-)